# How to make IE (8 and above) behave like Chrome when displaying disabled options

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a select with a search field attached. When the user searches for a value, the list shows the values that match that search.

In IE 8 and above, the unmatched results show as gray out:

[image]

But in Chrome, there are no gray out results. Only the results matching the search are visible:

[image]

How can I make IE behave like Chrome? I've tried CSS pseudo classes but didn't worked.

Comment: I'd be interested in how you are disabling the options on search because IE11 and Chrome behave the same way for disabled items - https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/oWVxeV

Comment: Hi Israel Bautista, welcome to [so]. Please show your code - the HTML, the CSS, etc. You can update your question by clicking on the **[edit]** link under the post. Thanks.